# Getting the error: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, office-dev-pnp

I have a function app to which receives and process webhook notifications from a SharePoint online list. It has been working fine for the past 8 months, today I started getting below exception:

"The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing"

for the below code ( I believe so):

using (var pnpContext = _pnpContextFactory.Create(new Uri(webHook.SharePointSiteUrl)))

I have absolutely no idea what went wrong suddenly, can any one please help?

Thanks